# Variable in os.system

Tags: python

I am using `os.system` method in Python to open a file in Linux.
But I don't know how to pass the variable (a) inside the os.system command

```
import os
a=4
os.system('gedit +a test.txt')
```

How can i pass the variable as an integer inside the command?

Comment: I believe you meant `os.system('gedit +{} test.txt'.format(a))`

Answer (score 8):

```
os.system('gedit +%d test.txt' % (a,))
```

It is recommended to use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess) instead of `os.system`:

```
subprocess.call(['gedit', '+%d' % (a,), 'test.txt'])
```

Comment: It's good to get in the habit of *always* using an explicit tuple for the other argument to `%`: `'...' % (a, )`.

Comment: @chepner Improved. Thanks for nagging. :)

Comment: @cherry84  You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system("gedit +" + str(a) + " test.txt")
```

Comment: It gives an error (cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects)

Comment: my bad ,All fixed now, You have to cast the integer to a string